# How do I access metadata annotations from a class?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I have a Dart class that is annotated with metadata:

```dart
class Awesome {
  final String msg;
  const Awesome(this.msg);

  String toString() => msg;
}

@Awesome('it works!')
class Cool {

}
```

I want to see if `Cool` was annotated, and if so, with what. How do I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `dart:mirrors` library to access metadata annotations.

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Awesome {
  final String msg;
  const Awesome(this.msg);

  String toString() => msg;
}

@Awesome('it works!')
class Cool {

}

void main() {
  ClassMirror classMirror = reflectClass(Cool);
  List<InstanceMirror> metadata = classMirror.metadata;
  var obj = metadata.first.reflectee;
  print(obj); // it works!
}
```

To learn more, read about the [ClassMirror#metadata](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-mirrors.ClassMirror#id_metadata) method.

Comment: @Ahoy Yes. Please ask that question on StackOverflow and I'm sure you'll get a full answer. :)

Comment: What about flutter?

Comment: @Bojmaliev Flutter removed mirror library in its SDK. But you can do it with [Reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable)