# How to get the value from metadata, in Dart?

Tags: dart, metadata, dart-mirrors

Dart code:

```dart
@Table("users")
class User {}
```

And the metadata declaration:

```dart
class Table {
    final String name;
    const Table(this.name);
}
```

I can get the metadata `@Table` by following code:

```dart
var classMirror = reflectClass(User);
var metadata = classMirror.metadata;
print(metadata);
```

Which prints:

```dart
[InstanceMirror on Instance of 'Table']
```

But I don't know how to get the `users` from it :(

Comment: This is then a somewhat different question than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255368

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [InstanceMirror.getField](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_mirrors/InstanceMirror.html#getField) :

```dart
metadata.getField(#name);
```