# Finding out if one annotated variable in Dart has been accessed/mutated?

Tags: database, annotations, dart, persistence, metadata

Looking at resources and documentation online, I have found out that you can access metadata annotations from classes or fields ([How do I access metadata annotations from a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255368/how-do-i-access-metadata-annotations-from-a-class) or [How to get the value from metadata, in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555598/how-to-get-the-value-from-metadata-in-dart?lq=1), for instance).

But I would like to know how to see, after a variable has been annotated with a metadata annotation (such as @Persist), if that variable has been accessed or changed. That I wasn't able to find how to do it.

The application I have in mind for this is to be able to make a variable to transparently persist to a database (whenever the variable is accessed or mutated) by means of annotating that variable. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the observable package does what you want

see [How to share data structures with Polymer on both client and server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788028) for an example